# How can we disable UseNagleAlgorithm in RestSharp v107+? [restsharp]

Tags: httpclient, restsharp

In RestSharp v107+ ConfigureWebRequest was removed and we were using it in this way.

```
_client.ConfigureWebRequest(request => { request.ServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = Configuration.UseNagleAlgorithm; });
```

What is the alternative approach in v107+ to disable NagleAlgoritm?
I can see that you have this now below but I am not seeing anything related UseNagleAlgorithm

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(Configuration.Url)
{
    ThrowOnAnyError = true,
    MaxTimeout = Configuration.Timeout,
    Expect100Continue = false
};
```

I expect you to provide a way of setting this UseNagleAlgorithm because it improves latency especially on rate limiter approach.

Comment: You can still use `ServicePoint` static properties if you use .NET Framework. If you are on modern .NET, RestSharp uses `SocketsHttpHandler` https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25881